# F#: What is the relationship of an Add method and an IObserver<>

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I have the following code working code that I derived from a Pluralsight video from Mark Seeman. I do not understand how the last line works.

```
let sharpObjectCollection = ConcurrentBag<Envelope<SharpObject>>()
let sharpObjectSubject = new Subjects.Subject<Envelope<SharpObject>>()
sharpObjectSubject.Subscribe sharpObjectCollection.Add |> ignore
```

Looking through the [documentation for Subscribe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229065(v=vs.103).aspx), I see that it takes an [IObserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.103).aspx) as an argument, but I am passing it the [ConcurrentBag.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394995(v=vs.110).aspx).

What is going on here? Is this a feature of F#? Can I do this in c# too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is calling [this extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402849.aspx) which defines an overload of `Subscribe` which takes an `Action<T>` onNext handler. You can also do this in C#:

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<Envelope<SharpObject>>();
var subject = new Subject<Envelope<SharpObject>>();
subject.Subscribe(bag.Add);
```

Comment: That is the answer. How did you find that? Weird side note, you cannot accept answer in the first three minutes of asking.